# Playback of Streams Are Taking Longer with Android KitKat (AudioTrack + MediaCodec Solution)

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, android-mediacodec, audiotrack

I am using MediaCodec + AudioTrack solution to stream MP3 music. It was working fine until the recent KitKat update. With KitKat, the playback begins after approximately 14-15 seconds, whereas on JellyBean it was taking no more than a few seconds. What has been changed with the KitKat regarding the MediaCodec and/or AudioTrack?

Here's the log output:

```
04-07 23:49:33.582: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): ChromiumHTTPDataSource jni::getJavaVM()
04-07 23:49:34.742: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): mDisconnectAtHighwatermark = 0, cacheConfig is NULL(1)
04-07 23:49:34.747: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:36.477: D/HTTPBase(8055): [1] Network BandWidth = 0 Kbps
04-07 23:49:36.477: D/NuCachedSource2(8055): Remaining (64K), HighWaterThreshold (20480)
04-07 23:49:36.477: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:36.477: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
04-07 23:49:36.477: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
04-07 23:49:36.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:38.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:38.502: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:38.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:40.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:40.502: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:40.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:42.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:42.502: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:42.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:44.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:44.502: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:44.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:46.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:46.507: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:46.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:48.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:48.507: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:48.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:50.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:50.507: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:50.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:52.447: D/HTTPBase(8055): [2] Network BandWidth = 59 Kbps
04-07 23:49:52.447: D/NuCachedSource2(8055): Remaining (127K), HighWaterThreshold (20480)
04-07 23:49:52.447: D/NuCachedSource2(8055): readInternal - late!!!
04-07 23:49:52.447: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:52.447: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
04-07 23:49:52.447: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
04-07 23:49:52.452: D/StreamPlayerService(8055): MIME TYPE: audio/mpeg
04-07 23:49:52.452: I/ACodec(8055):  [] Now uninitialized
04-07 23:49:52.452: I/OMXClient(8055): Using client-side OMX mux.
04-07 23:49:52.457: I/ACodec(8055): [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Loaded
04-07 23:49:52.457: I/ACodec(8055): [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Loaded->Idle
04-07 23:49:52.462: I/ACodec(8055): [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Idle->Executing
04-07 23:49:52.467: I/ACodec(8055): [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Executing
04-07 23:49:52.472: D/StreamPlayerService(8055): Output format has changed to {sample-rate=22050, channel-count=2, what=1869968451, mime=audio/raw}
```

Comment: I'd like to hear the comments of the MediaCodec expert fadden, who had (introduced me the MediaCodec API (thanks again)...

Comment: I haven't worked with audio, so I'm afraid I can't be of much help here.

Comment: What protocol are you trying to play?  E.g. progressive HTTP or RTSP or something other?

Comment: I am playing streaming media (MP3) over HTTP.

Comment: There are no significant changes to MediaExtractor or NuCachedSource2 between KK and JB, so I am not sure what is the cause of the added delay.

Comment: From your logs it seems that the HTTP read keeps timing out, but I have not found those logs on AOSP to be able to dig deeper.

Comment: Yes, neither could I. Where might be those outputs coming from?